# Storing DataGrid in List

Tags: c#, list, datagrid, datagridview, process

With my program I'm trying to automatize another program of which there can be multiple instances. I've already written functionality that will watch the processlist and detect all processes of the program that I want to automatize.

It will store some basic informations about found instances into this ConcurrentDictionary which has its ProcessId as key and the class ProgramToWatch as value:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProgramToWatch> ProgramToWatchDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProgramToWatch>();

public class ProgramToWatch
{
    public string ListItemName { get; set; }
    public Process BEProcess { get; set; }
    public string BEMainWindowTitle { get; set; }
    public Application BEApplication { get; set; }
    public Window BEWindow { get; set; }
    public bool isLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public List<ProgramToWatchDataGrid> BEDataGrid = new List<ProgramToWatchDataGrid>();
}
```

**Now the part I am having problems with.** The program I want to watch has a DataGridView which I want to copy into my dictionary. For this I have the BEDataGrid List. The list is using this class as its type:

```
public class ProgramToWatchDataGrid
{
    public int ListID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Now to store it, I create another instance of the ProgramToWatchDataGrid (called updateGrid), write all the data I read into it, and place this into my Dictionary (I simplified). To do this, I iterate through the DataGrid (first while loop), row for row and copy the updateGrid  to my Dictionary - in the second while loop I display the values to verify:

```
public void ReadDataGridView(int ProcessId)
{
    ProgramToWatchDataGrid updateGrid = new ProgramToWatchDataGrid();

    //read and store every row
    int i=0;
    while(i<=totalRowsInGrid)
    {
        updateGrid.ListId = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
        updateGrid.Name = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
        updateGrid.Mail = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
        ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid.Insert(i, updateGrid);
        Display(ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid[i].Mail);
    }

    Display("Elements: " + ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BeDataGrid.Count);

    //display every rows mail
    i=0;
    while(i<=totalRowsInGrid)
    {
        Display("HI: " + ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid[i].Mail);
        i++;
    }
}
```

The way I understand it, the Information rows I read should now be located in ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid[accordingRow] because I inserted the Information at that place.

**The strange thing is, that this output will be produced:**

```
[01:19] christoferlindstrm@yahoo.com
[01:19] eliseisaksson@yahoo.com
[01:19] peter@pan.com
[01:19] Elements: 3
[01:19] HI: peter@pan.com
[01:19] HI: peter@pan.com
[01:19] HI: peter@pan.com
```

So right after I've inserted it, the List contains the right value. But after it will always be the last value that was read? Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. 
You should create the instance of the object to be added in the while, otherwise you are using only one instance which happens to get different values in your cycle. And of course it will end up with the last value you have inserted.

```
public void ReadDataGridView(int ProcessId)
{
    ProgramToWatchDataGrid updateGrid = null;

    //read and store every row
    int i=0;
    while(i<=totalRowsInGrid)
    {
        //create a new instance
        updateGrid = new ProgramToWatchDataGrid();
        updateGrid.ListId = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
        updateGrid.Name = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
        updateGrid.Mail = DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;

        ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid.Insert(i, updateGrid);
        Display(ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid[i].Mail);
    }

    Display("Elements: " + ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BeDataGrid.Count);

    //display every rows mail
    i=0;
    while(i<=totalRowsInGrid)
    {
        Display("HI: " + ProgramToWatchDictionary[ProcessID].BEDataGrid[i].Mail);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Input is, e.g. for the mail row0 christoferlindstrm@yahoo.com, row1 eliseisaksson@yahoo.com, row peter@pan.com. So the output displays these right first but somehow it is lost again right after I inserted it.

Comment: just tested it and it's working. this seems like the logic thing to do as well, thank you very much! have a nice day.